# How to send data from raspberry pi(using wifi dongle) to android phone

Tags: android, networking, raspberry-pi, wifi

Here is my problem. I want to connect raspberry pi to android and transfer files. But I want to achieve this through wifi dongle in pi and wifi in android phone. No routers.Is this even feasible and if yes pointing towards any tutorials or insight would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find some usefull information here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=49420